# Byte array to String with no internal processing, e.g. 

Tags: export, string-manipulation, conversion, character-encoding, named-characters

UTF8 defines a way to map from bytes to glyphs.  In particular, glyphs with code <128 can be 1 byte, glyphs with code <2048 can be 2 bytes, etc. up to 4 bytes.  For instance, the white queen `♕` has code `9813` and is is encoded as the three bytes `{226,153,149}`.

I want to pass a String object containing such a byte array to `` FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard `` and/or other functions.  However, for many 'named' characters, calling `ByteArrayToString@ByteArray` autoconverts the byte array to an escape sequence such as \[WhiteQueen] in this example.

## Question

How can I convert a ByteArray to a String with no internal processing or replacements?  A hypothetical function `barr2str` should work such that

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard@ barr2str@{226,153,149}
```

always yields a unicode character instead of an escape sequence.  Do we have to resort to compiled c passing strategies (and if so, how)?

## Supplement

Following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding, here is a function that converts from a unicode codepoint to an appropriate byte array

```
Remove[unicode2barr]
unicode2barr[codepoint_] := If[# < 128, {#}, 
  FromDigits[PadLeft[Prepend[#, 0], 8, 1], 2] & /@ 
   Prepend[Partition[#2, 6], #] & @@ 
    TakeDrop[PadLeft[#, 1 + #2], 7 - #2/5] &[#, 
     Ceiling[Length@# - 1, 5]] &@IntegerDigits[#, 2]] &@codepoint
```

It may be tested as follows:

```
{FromCharacterCode@#, ByteArrayToString@ByteArray@unicode2barr@#}&\
  /@{946, FromDigits["20AC",16], 9813, 78064 (* your favorite codepoints *)}
```