# Define or remove a long form input \[xyz]

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, character-encoding, named-characters

There are "InputAliases" ⵗ*xyz*ⵗ, "InputAutoReplacements" *xyz*<kbd>space</kbd>, and things we'll call "long form inputs" \[*xyz*].  It's easy to view and modify the former two replacements with CurrentValue.

Can I add a new long input form `\[xyz]` which gets substituted with `"abc"`?

Better yet, can I remove or temporarily disable one or all existing long inputs?  The ideal solution `disableLongForms` would act such that

```
disableLongForms[]
Characters@ToString@FullForm@"\[PartialD]" ===\
  Join @@ Characters /@ {"\"\[PartialD", "]\""} (*should be False*)
```

Comment: Note that the full name `\[xyz]` is what is stored in the notebook (in cell boxes) and is parsed when a notebook is opened. I doubt very much this could be disabled. As for extending it, maybe someone will have a way, other than auto replacements.

Comment: Is there any way of obtaining a raw unicode character such as `ζ` which isn't expanded to `\[Zeta]` in a notebook?  I tried inserting it in an external editor and got an error loading the nb.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it from being replaced? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This question is related to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287239/byte-array-to-string-with-no-internal-processing-e-g, ultimately for a platform independent answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook.